# how to find partial derivative of complex numbers

Tags: calculus

How would I find the partial derivative of a?

$ Y = [(a-ib)/\sqrt{2}*(a+ib)/\sqrt{2}]^{2}$

When I expand the square, does it look like this:

$(a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}+b^{4})/4$

making the partial derivative:

$a^{3} +ab^{2}$ ?

I think I am missing something...

Comment: Looks right to me. $(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2$ so your formula should be $\left(\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}\right)^2$, which it is.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Thanks, that was very quick!  I appreciate it!

Comment: The partial derivative...wrt $\,a\,$ , I presume...?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yes, I should have included that!